# How detect actual language of webpage translated via Google translate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-translate

I need to detect the translated language and ideally make some class maybe to body. After that via this class edit CSS of webpage. I have no problem with solutions with jQuery or pure JavaScript.
I need this because different languages has different length of words and this can make me problem with design. I need solved this like

```
.language_cz .some_class{
  font-size: 14px;
}
.language_en .some_class{
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

I make this translate via https://gtranslate.io/. This is pure Google translate.

Code of translate is:

```
   <div class="obal_mutace">
<span class="aktualni_mutace">CZ</span>
<div class="blok_mutace_in">
            <a href="#" onclick="doGTranslate('cs|cs');return false;" title="Czech" class="gflag nturl"><span data-id="CZ" class="polozka_mutace_in">CZ</span></a>
  <a href="#" onclick="doGTranslate('cs|en');return false;" title="English" class="gflag nturl"><span data-id="EN" class="polozka_mutace_in">EN</span></a>
  <a href="#" onclick="doGTranslate('cs|de');return false;" title="German" class="gflag nturl"><span data-id="DE" class="polozka_mutace_in">DE</span></a>
  <a href="#" onclick="doGTranslate('cs|ru');return false;" title="Russian" class="gflag nturl"><span data-id="RU" class="polozka_mutace_in">RU</span></a>
  <a href="#" onclick="doGTranslate('cs|fr');return false;" title="French" class="gflag nturl"><span data-id="FR" class="polozka_mutace_in">FR</span></a>
  <a href="#" onclick="doGTranslate('cs|it');return false;" title="Italian" class="gflag nturl"><span data-id="IT" class="polozka_mutace_in">IT</span></a>
  <a href="#" onclick="doGTranslate('cs|pt');return false;" title="Portuguese" class="gflag nturl"><span data-id="PT" class="polozka_mutace_in">PT</span></a>
  <a href="#" onclick="doGTranslate('cs|es');return false;" title="Spanish" class="gflag nturl"><span data-id="ES" class="polozka_mutace_in">ES</span></a>
  <div id="google_translate_element2"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="funkce/transl_init.js?v=1.0.1"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit2"></script>
</div>
```

in "transl_init.js" I have:

```
function googleTranslateElementInit2() {new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'cs',autoDisplay: false}, 'google_translate_element2');}

/* <![CDATA[ */
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,r){e=function(c){return(c<a?'':e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--)r[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c);k=[function(e){return r[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);return p}('6 7(a,b){n{4(2.9){3 c=2.9("o");c.p(b,f,f);a.q(c)}g{3 c=2.r();a.s(\'t\'+b,c)}}u(e){}}6 h(a){4(a.8)a=a.8;4(a==\'\')v;3 b=a.w(\'|\')[1];3 c;3 d=2.x(\'y\');z(3 i=0;i<d.5;i++)4(d[i].A==\'B-C-D\')c=d[i];4(2.j(\'k\')==E||2.j(\'k\').l.5==0||c.5==0||c.l.5==0){F(6(){h(a)},G)}g{c.8=b;7(c,\'m\');7(c,\'m\')}}',43,43,'||document|var|if|length|function|GTranslateFireEvent|value|createEvent||||||true|else|doGTranslate||getElementById|google_translate_element2|innerHTML|change|try|HTMLEvents|initEvent|dispatchEvent|createEventObject|fireEvent|on|catch|return|split|getElementsByTagName|select|for|className|goog|te|combo|null|setTimeout|500'.split('|'),0,{}))
/* ]]> */
```

I used it on my webpage project http://www.kalimera-recko.cz/. I used Google translate in head of web on the left from search input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correct you want to style your page according to the used language.

On your page you set the language attribute on the html tag.

```
<html class="js" style="height: 100%;" lang="cs">
```

So you can address it in your css with this:

```
html[lang="cs"] .some_class
```

**[EDIT]__________________**

A cookie is set
"googtrans" to the value /cs/en if translated to englisch and to te value /cs/de if translated to german. 
You can find out the value of the cookie with javascript or jQuery

```
document.cookie
```

It returns a string where you need to search for the "googtrans" value.

You can get the language with this:

```
var cookie = document.cookie;
var position = cookie.indexOf("googtrans");
var language = cookie.substring(position+10, position + 16);
```

This code can be optimized if you search for the end of the value ';' instead of using fixed numbers. 
But this will do what you need.

You may also should use a try/catch and see if the cookie exists because it doesn't exist for your original language.

Comment: But if I transleted page via Google translator then this tag is still "cs" and text is in this time maybe English. 
I tried change something like this via jQuery on click to some languge, but if user came to web and change language then ok, but when he go to another page in my web, then translator automaticlly translate content of web, without users click on different language, to his first selected language.

Comment: Ah, okay. Now I see where your problem is.

Comment: Just updated my answer. Do you need help with the string operations?

Comment: For read content of this cookie I need to use http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/ ?

Comment: No. Only javascript is fine.

Comment: is this still working ? Can't find googtrans in cookies anywhere.